# How do I pass selected value from a struts2 iterator to modal popup

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I have a list on jsp page.

On clicking Refer I want to display the username on the modal popup.

I can use javascript but I am not sure how to the clicked rows username to the value of the button.

I can not use submit button because of modal popup. Or is there any way to store the clicked username ?

Something like:

1. Jon 15 click
2. Tom 18 Click
3. Ana 14 Click

Assuming values are coming from request.specs. Hitting "Click" shall open a modal popup to show the clicked row details.

```xml
<s:iterator value="#request.specs" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <s:property value="userName"/>

            <button type="button" 
                    name="uName" 
                   class="btn btn-primary" 
             data-toggle="modal"  
             data-target="#appointment" 
                   value=""> Refer </button>

        </td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: I want to display username which is <s:property value="username"/> on the modal pop up which opens when I hit Refer button.